# how to realize socket connection was lost in server side after client run receive function in python

Tags: python

I have a program hande some devices in network. the program create a process for each device and each process run socket.recv function in a loop to receive messages from connected device.
when I turn device off and then turn it on, the connection between program and device would be lost but the recv function would not return any things or raise any exception and the process stay blocked.
How can handle this problem
this is my code :

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
ip = sys.argv[1]
port = sys.argv[2]
pingInterval = float(sys.argv[3])
deviceId = sys.argv[4]

print("A card reader started for ", ip)

Thread(target=setThePingerThread, args=(pingInterval,)).start()

while True:   
    clientsock = socket (AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM)
    connectionSuccessful = False
    while not connectionSuccessful:
        try:        
            clientsock.connect((ip, int(port)))
            connectionSuccessful = True
            print('socket connected to ', ip, port)
        except Exception as e:
            print('Can''t connect to the device! device ip =>', ip)
            time.sleep(5000)
            pass

    try:   
        mybuffer = bytes()
        data = bytes()
        cardNumbers = []

        while True:   
            mybuffer = clientsock.recv(100)
            data = data + mybuffer
            cardNumbers, data = retreiveCardNumbers(data)
            #print('debug: cardNumbers=', cardNumbers, ' data=',data, ' data-decoded=',data.decode("ascii"))
            for cardNumber in cardNumbers:
                print('A card hit:', cardNumber)
                sendToQueue(cardNumber, deviceId)                

    except Exception as e:
        print('Error processing card number! device ip =>', ip, e)
```

Answer (score 0):

Referring to

> the process stay blocked

I do not know the code of `setThePingerThread` but I guess the error is solved with this:

```
thread = Thread(target=setThePingerThread, args=(pingInterval,))
thread.deamon = True
thread.start()
```

`thread.deamon` is usually False which makes the program wait for the end of that thread.